# Rejecting an admit to Computer Science Graduate School and re-applying

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

The situation is that if I get accepted from this school, say A, I would like to go but there are certain circumstances such that if they unfold, then I would like to go to school next year. So should I even apply to A? If I reject an acceptance from A and then reapply the next year, does it put me in the bad books of the Graduate committee of that school for rejecting and reapplying?

Comment: You should ask the school what their policy is on deferring an offer of admission.

Answer (score 3):

Do apply. If you don't get admitted, nothing needs to happen. If you do get accepted, accept the position if you're in a position to do so. If you can't accept the position, then talk to the graduate adviser and see if they're willing to defer you going there by a year. Most departments will be willing to do this -- they've already found you fitting for the job, so whether you come this year or next is not all that important to them. Deferrals for good reason are not uncommon.

The point is that if you don't apply, you won't get admitted this year (if circumstances would allow you to take the position), and you don't have a guarantee that you'll be admitted next year either.